# Creating custom search engine component for Joomla

Tags: joomla, lucene, solr

I am building a simple website using **Joomla 1.5**. As everyone knows Joomla's default search capability sucks.

After googling a little bit, I found out about `Lucene` + `Solr`. I want to know if there's a way I can incorporate `Lucene` + `Solr` into the default **Joomla** search's component.

My idea is `Lucene` + `Solr` will do all the heavy lifting of searching but the result will still by displayed by Joomla's search component.

Basically I want to know where I can "hook" `Lucene` + `Solr` into **Joomla**. `Lucene` + `Solr` will intercept all the search queries and will also overrides the search result output.

Any pointers or tutorials where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

The [TNR ESearch](http://www.tnrjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/cat_view/16-tnr-esearch) Joomla extension looks to be what you want. You should be able to configure it using the URL for a Solr index of your choosing.